# Custom Calendar - Days Left in Month

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I'm working on creating a custom calendar that shows 2 consecutive weeks in one row.

I am not trying to make a typical 7 day,4 week calendar that the common JS UI libraries provide.

I'm currently stuck at filling in proceeding and following calendar days. I don't know why, but I hit a road block where I can't seem to figure out how to fill the calendar days with the months/next months days. (I can label today properly, but I can fill previous or upcoming days)

Any help is appreciated, here is my code.

HTML:

```
<div id="Cal">
       <table>
           <thead>
               <tr>
                    <th colspan="15" style="text-align:center;"></th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
               <tr class="Second_Header">
                   <td></td>
                   <td>Mon</td>
                   <td>Tue</td>
                   <td>Wed</td>
                   <td>Thu</td>
                   <td>Fri</td>
                   <td>Sat</td>
                   <td style="border-right:solid 1px #000;">Sun</td>
                   <td>Mon</td>
                   <td>Tue</td>
                   <td>Wed</td>
                   <td>Thu</td>
                   <td>Fri</td>
                   <td>Sat</td>
                   <td>Sun</td>
               </tr>
               <tr id="Days"  class="Second_Header">
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td  style="background: #443E3E;">John Doe</td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
               </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td  style="background: #443E3E;">Bob Smith</td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
               </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td  style="background: #443E3E;">Joe McDonald</td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
               </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
   </div>
```

JS/jQuery:

```
$(function () {
        $("#Cal tbody tr td:nth-child(7)").addClass("WeekEnd");
        var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "Spetember", "October", "November", "December"],
        currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
        currentMonth = (new Date).getMonth();
        currentDate = (new Date).getDate();
        currentDay = (new Date).getDay();
        monthDays = [];
        monthDays[0] = 31;
        if (currentYear % 4 === 0) {  // if not a leapyear, feb. has 28 days
            monthDays[1] = 28;
        }
        else {
            monthDays[1] = 29;  // if a leapyear, feb. has 29 days
        }
        monthDays[2] = 31;
        monthDays[3] = 30;
        monthDays[4] = 31;
        monthDays[5] = 30;
        monthDays[6] = 31;
        monthDays[7] = 31;
        monthDays[8] = 30;
        monthDays[9] = 31;
        monthDays[10] = 30;
        monthDays[11] = 31;
        $("#Cal thead th").text((months[currentMonth])); // Set month
        if (currentDate >= (currentDate - monthDays[currentMonth]))  //Second half of month helps determine placement of today
        {
            $("#Days td").eq(currentDay+7).text(currentDate); // Set current day
            $("#Days td").eq(currentDay+7).addClass("today"); // Add class to current day

            $("#Days td:not(:first)").each(function () { // Fill remainder of week
                var UpcomingDays = monthDays[currentMonth] - currentDate
                console.log(UpcomingDays);
                if (UpcomingDays > 0) {

                }
                else {

                }
            });
        }
        else {      //First half of month helps determine placement of today
            $("#Days td").eq(currentDay).text(currentDate); // Set current day
            $("#Days td").eq(currentDay).addClass("today"); // Add class to current day

            $("#Days td:not(:first)").each(function () { // Fill remainder of week
                if ($(this).text() == "") {
                    if (currentDate <= monthDays[currentMonth]) {
                        $(this).text("FR");
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).text("FL");
                    }

                }
            });
            }
});
```

Here is a link to the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zB4Th/

Comment: I did something similar a while back - in a fiddle for you  http://jsfiddle.net/drjimmie1976/d5wma/. It's a dynamically generated calendar view using pure Javascript. It's unfinished - I haven't sorted out entering the previous next month's dates - and you'd need to update the code to make it show 2 weeks at a time, but thought it might be of some use. Sorry it's not quite there...

Comment: Just updated it for the 14 day format. Looking at it now the code isn't great, but hopefully something you can work with. Im heads down at the moment but will try to update to add the previous/next months.